# Accessing json array in ajax method is giving undefined as output. Trying to access iterate over response object in ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

In my servlet I am populating list of Products selected by user for comparison and converting it to JSON .The product data consists of productcode,name,price,full image,thumbnail image etc. These are some of the Attributes

```
    List<ProductData> comparedProducts=getProductPanelDetails(prodCodeList);
    json=new Gson().toJson(comparedProducts);
    System.out.println(json);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
```

My JSON string printed from the servlet is as shown below

```
[
  {
    "productID": "P0001",
    "productName": "Nexus 5",
    "price": "INR 25,000",
    "image": "images/nexus5.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "images/thumbnail_nexus5.jpg"
  },
  {
    "productID": "P0002",
    "productName": "Nexus 6",
    "price": "INR 45,000",
    "image": "images/nexus6.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "images/thumbnail-nexus6.jpg"
  }
]
```

I am not sure how should I read this inside my ajax function. I want to dynamically create a panel and add these products to it. This function is getting executed whenever user clicks 'Add to compare' checkbox from jsp page

```
 $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'productSelected',
           contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;',
           data: {productCode:productCode,check:check},
           dataType:'json',
           cache: false,
           success: function (response) {
               for(i in response)
            { 
             alert(i.productID);
             alert(i.productName);
            };// This gives undefined as output
               alert("Record Has been Saved in Database");
           }
         });
```

Here product code is the productId selected by user and check signifies whether user has checked or unchecked the checkbox. It is a boolean variable. Can you please help me access the ProductDataList in my ajax function. I am not sure how to get the output json in the ajax to display it on front end. I tried a for loop with response object but it didnt work.However if i try response[0].productName then it does give me the name of product. But i am not sure how should I get all the values in the List of Product Data

Comment: *"I am sorry I have to keep on typing as stackoverflow doesnt allow me to submit my question saying " add some context to explain your code""* - well if it does say that, then what is a *good* idea is to actually simplify the code posted and add some comments and what is a *bad* idea is to add meaningless words ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write your controller like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/compare")
public class CompareController extends AbstractController
{
    @Autowired
    private ProductFacade productFacade;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/products", method ={RequestMethod.GET}, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<ProductData> productCompare(@RequestParam("productCodes") final String[] productCodes)
    {
        final List<ProductOption> options = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(ProductOption.BASIC, ProductOption.PRICE));
        final List<ProductData> productList = new ArrayList<ProductData>();
        for (final String code : productCodes)
        {
            productList.add(productFacade.getProductForCodeAndOptions(code, options));
        }
        return productList;
    }
}
```

Now, check are you getting a correct response?

`alert(JSON.stringify(response));`

If you are getting response correctly then you can iterate over response JSON.

Like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url+"?"+prodCodeList,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        response.forEach(function(product)
        {
              alert(product.productID);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> This gives undefined as output

```
 for(i in response)
```

Here, `i` is index/offset of array and not the object itself, use `response[i]` instead i.e. `response[i].productID` and so on.

```js
var response = [{
    "productID": "P0001",
    "productName": "Nexus 5",
    "price": "INR 25,000",
    "image": "images/nexus5.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "images/thumbnail_nexus5.jpg"
  },
  {
    "productID": "P0002",
    "productName": "Nexus 6",
    "price": "INR 45,000",
    "image": "images/nexus6.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "images/thumbnail-nexus6.jpg"
  }
];

for (var i in response) {
  console.log('i=', i, ', product id=', response[i].productID);
}
```

You may go for Array#forEach like:

```js
var response = [{
    "productID": "P0001",
    "productName": "Nexus 5",
    "price": "INR 25,000",
    "image": "images/nexus5.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "images/thumbnail_nexus5.jpg"
  },
  {
    "productID": "P0002",
    "productName": "Nexus 6",
    "price": "INR 45,000",
    "image": "images/nexus6.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "images/thumbnail-nexus6.jpg"
  }
];

response.forEach(function(o) {
  console.log('product id=', o.productID);
});
```

Comment: I had forgotten to parse my json response. It started working after I added this :-

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);